# Using data from a text file as a condition in an if statement

Tags: java, string, equality

I am attempting to read from a file in Java, and use the string I get as a condition in an `if` statement. I know the reader is correct (it works in other programs), but when I try to do something like

```
if(reader.getVariable() == "A") {
    do x
}
else {
    do y
}
```

It will always do y, even though printing out the `getVariable()` method returns "A". Why is this?

Comment: Use equals method instead of ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare strings in java, you should use the equals() method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, always use the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check whether two strings have the same value:

```
if(reader.getVariable().equals("A")) {
```

The `==` operator doesn't work because it checks whether two strings are the exact same *instance*, which they aren't in this case.